# I can't use leafmap in pycharm to display an interactive map

Tags: jupyter, gis, geospatial, sam

Here is my code:
import os
import leafmap
from samgeo import SamGeo, show_image, download_file, overlay_images, tms_to_geotiff

m = leafmap.Map(center=[37.8713, -122.2580], zoom=17, height="800px")
m.add_basemap("SATELLITE")
m

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdbsb.png)

I had set up the correct conda environment

I tried to reproduce Wu Qiusheng's[here](https://github.com/opengeos/segment-geospatial) code, but I'm failed